How to implement Depth First Search on a Weighted Adjacency List Graph?
I'm working on a depth first search of a weighted graph from an adjacency list. I know that technically weighted shouldn't make a difference here, but it does in how my vectors are setup and I'm not sure how to proceed. I believe it's failing when I go through the ranged based for loop because my adjListWeightedcontains pairs in the second embedded vector and I'm not sure how to adjust my function to correct for that.
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> adjListWeighted(1);
    adjListWeighted[0].push_back({1, 5});
    for (int i : adjListWeighted[0]) {
    }
}

This is the error that I receive from the compiler:

error: cannot convert 'std::pair<int, int>' to 'int' in initialization


Please prepare a [mcve] and include it in the quesiton. In the code you posted here adjListWeighted[0] is out of bounds because the vector is empty

it's also trying to bind a pair of ints to an int

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I fed the asker that example and ignored runtime UB because the problem is the code doesn't compile. Will fix in a moment

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Updated example code and added error message. Simply unsure how to adjust my for loop to properly look at the pair inside the vector.

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but
for (int i : adjListWeighted[0]) {
    ...
}

will not work (even if adjListWeighted had contents) because it is a vector of pairs of integers not integers. You need the range element variable to be a pair or need to use structured binding to assign to two integer variables.
As below:

#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

using weighted_edge = std::pair<int, int>;
using weighted_graph = std::vector<std::vector<weighted_edge>>;

void dfs(int start, const weighted_graph& g) {
    std::unordered_set<int> visited;
    std::stack<weighted_edge> stack;
    stack.emplace(start, 0);

    while (!stack.empty()) {
        auto [vert, weight] = stack.top();
        stack.pop();

        if (visited.contains(vert)) {
            continue;
        }
        visited.insert(vert);

        // do something with vert and/or weight...
        std::cout << vert << " : " << weight << "\n";

        for (const auto& edge : g.at(vert)) {
            stack.push(edge);
        }

    }
}

int main() {
    weighted_graph graph = {
        {{1,3},{2,3}},
        {{3,5},{2,4}},
        {{3,5}},
        {}
    };
    dfs(0, graph);
    return 0;
}


Note: The magic sauce is here: for (const auto& edge : g.at(vert)). The auto leaves it up to the compiler to figure out what the vector contains and type the indexed variable accordingly. The const promises you won't change the value received (traps potential bugs where you accidentally change the value and gives the compiler the ability to make some nifty optimizations) and the & is a good ol' reference so you don't have to copy stuff around.

This helps a lot, thank you. I've just never used pairs or multiple embedded vectors so was having a hard time wrapping my brain around it and the code I posted was from what I had for unweighted dfs.
